# Antifreeze in my engine, and now it's making a ticking noise

Tags: engine, ford, f-150

I changed a busted intake out, also changed the plugs.

Some old antifreeze get in the plug holes when I pulled the plugs.

I have reassembled the car, but it runs bad and has a ticking noise.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Chad, please post something with the audio of the noise.  I doubt a little bit of anti-freeze is going to make that noise.  In fact, I don't see how it could.  I would imagine that the noise source could be poorly mounted manifold and it's the sound of air getting sucked into the system.  Any additional information you can add to your post, pictures, audio, video will help the community help you.  Good luck.

Comment: Off topic, but trying to give any help possible...  Last minute rental car deals can be found in many cities for less than $20/day.  Some people don't realize how affordable it can be, especially for emergencies like this.

Comment: @DucatiKiller. If he let a decent amount of antifreeze into the cylinder, then he could easily have damaged a piston, conrod or the crank when he started it.  Hopefully this is not the case, but it wouldn't surprise me with the symptoms.